# Segmenting the strings received from serial port

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string

I am receiving sensor datas through the serial port using Xbee module. The sensors are connected to Arduino and they are sending datas to the zigbee connected to my laptop. here, is the code i am using to show the received datas.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Change to the baud rate of the port B2400, B9600, B19200 etc as per Arduino board is sending */
#define SPEED B9600

/* Change to the serial port you want to use /dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyS0, etc. */
#define PORT "/dev/ttyS1"


/* Sensor raw datas */
int accLowX, accLowY, accLowZ;
int accHighX, accHighY, accHighZ;


int main( ){
    int fd = open( PORT, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY );
    if (fd <0) {perror(PORT); exit(-1); }
    struct termios options;

    bzero(&options, sizeof(options));
    options.c_cflag = SPEED | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD | IGNPAR;
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

    int r;
    char buf[255];
    char sensorDatas[255];

    while( 1 ){

        r = read( fd, buf, 255 );
        buf[r]=0;
        memcpy(sensorDatas, buf, strlen(buf)+1);
        printf( "%s", sensorDatas);

        // separate the strings for sensor datas




        //




    }


}
```

My Output of received datas are:

```
56-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:341 AHZ:421
57-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:354 AHY:341 AHZ:422
58-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
59-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
60-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:352 AHY:342 AHZ:422
61-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:421
62-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:354 AHY:342 AHZ:422
63-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
64-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
65-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:421
66-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:421
67-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
68-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
69-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:341 AHZ:421
70-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
71-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:352 AHY:342 AHZ:422
72-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
73-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
74-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:352 AHY:342 AHZ:422
75-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:352 AHY:342 AHZ:422
76-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
77-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
78-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:421
79-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
80-ALX:350 ALY:350 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:343 AHZ:422
81-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
82-ALX:350 ALY:349 ALZ:351 AHX:353 AHY:342 AHZ:422
```

Here i cannot use strlen function as it gives me the output 0 as r is set zo zero. without knowing the string length, i cannot proceed to segment it to get the following datas. 
Consider for received string 56, I want to store the following value in each iteration in the following the variables

```
accLowX = 350, accLowY = 349, accLowZ=351
accHighX =353, accHighY = 341, accHighZ =421;
```

How can i do it?

Comment: I don't get this part actually: _"as it gives me the output 0 as r is set zo zero"_ If `r` was set to zero, nothing was read? See [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html).

Comment: No, If buf[r]=0,  it will read till the end of bytes received. Else it gives me a lot of garbage value in addition. 

After memcpy, if i use strlen(sensorDatas) and print it, it gives me only zeros (0).

Comment: But then, you can use `strlen()` not? If `strlen()` results with 0, that implicitely means `r` must be zero.

Comment: Yes, it is obvious, r = 0, but sensorDatas is not zero. It is exactly the same string that we have received. why should strlen(sensorDatas) should give Zero? when it is printing the strings as shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by creating a string array and put each line in it (with `getline` maybe?) Then, you can use split function of boost and use a space as a delimiter. Then, put all of these in a temporary array. http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/ -> Boost String Algorithms: Split

After, just use the `find` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to identify each parameter and use a switch case for each one. Or, take the array and use it directly, since all position will be the same (ex: [0] = ALX:(Number), [1] = ALY:(Number), etc). Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sscanf` , something like this -

```
if(sscanf(s,"%*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d"
                   ,&accLowX,&accLowY,&accLowZ,&accHighX,&accHighY,&accHighZ))==6){
       // do something 
 }
```

Comment: @Student15  Yes, use `printf` to print  or if you want to do anything with values do that operations .

Comment: if(sscanf(sensorDatas,"%*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d"
                   ,&accLowX,&accLowY,&accLowZ,&accHighX,&accHighY,&accHighZ)==6) {
        // do something 
  
  printf( "accLowX : %d\n", accLowX);
  printf( "accLowY : %d\n", accLowY);
  printf( "accLowZ : %d\n", accLowZ);
  
  }


It didn't work :( It doesnot goes in to If LOOP

Comment: I want to make it like After Each string  (One complete line is received) , I store them in accLowX, accLowY...etc and process them..   After processing for that iteration will be finished i will store new values in those variable and process them

Comment: @Student15 put this inside your loop where you read values , this will do that . You `while` loop read values from file , put this inside it and do your processing

Comment: I did exactly as you said. But it doesnot show the printf values of accLowX,accLowY, accLowZ ..I think it is not going inside if loop. Can you please have a look here? 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxpjro55cvxyl4y/code.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Student15  I don't see any problem in your code , there , but just to be sure instead of `memcpy(sensorDatas, buf, strlen(buf)+1);` **->** `memcpy(sensorDatas, buf, strlen(buf));` . Try this , and add `'\0'` to `sensorDatas` after this .

Comment: I am very astonished to see this luckily. After 6500+ strings are received I found exactly what i wanted to do just for once :( 
    `6574-ALX:352 ALY:352 ALZ:353 AHX:352 AHY:368 AHZ:420 
    6575-ALX:352 ALY:352 ALZ:353 AHX:353 AHY:369 AHZ:421
    6576-ALX:352 ALY:352 ALZ:353 AHX:354 AHY:369 AHZ:420`
    
    `accLowX : 352
    accLowY : 352
    accLowZ : 353`

    `6577-ALX:352 ALY:352 ALZ:353 AHX:353 AHY:369 AHZ:421
    6578-ALX:351 ALY:352 ALZ:353 AHX:352 AHY:368 AHZ:420`

what should i do to get this value after each line. ?? My code is in the link above

Comment: @Student15 Maybe then you should check what `read()` returns , on error it gives `-1` , in case it encounters error. Please check its return for every read operation .

Comment: I cannot reply anymore as i dont have reputation. However i get read function value as 0 at each read.

Comment: @Student15 It returns `0` it means it encounters `EOF` , there is problem in reading I guess . Please read about function `read` to know more on it ,maybe as it encounter `'\n'`, returns .

Comment: I read it and it as follows "If no process has the pipe open for writing, read() shall return 0 to indicate end-of-file". However i have copied the buffer in to sensorDatas and it prints exactly the same line what i am sending through my arduino board.

Answer (score 0):

After your valuable suggestions, I found this way to solve my problem. This code is inspired by this [CodeSource](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html)

Modified Code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BAUDRATE B9600  /* baudrate settings are defined in <asm/termbits.h>, which is included by <termios.h> */
#define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyS1" /* change this definition for the correct port */
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1 /* POSIX compliant source */
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

volatile int STOP=FALSE; 

int main()
{
    int fd,c, res;
    struct termios oldtio,newtio;
    char buf[255];
    char sensorDatas[255];
    /* Sensor raw datas */
    int accLowX, accLowY, accLowZ;
    int accHighX, accHighY, accHighZ;
    /* 
    Open modem device for reading and writing and not as controlling tty
    because we don't want to get killed if linenoise sends CTRL-C.
    */
    fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY ); 
    if(fd <0) {
        perror(MODEMDEVICE); 
        exit(-1); 
        }

    tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio); /* save current serial port settings */
    //bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio)); /* clear struct for new port settings */

    /* 
    BAUDRATE: Set bps rate. You could also use cfsetispeed and cfsetospeed.
    CRTSCTS : output hardware flow control (only used if the cable has
            all necessary lines. See sect. 7 of Serial-HOWTO)
    CS8     : 8n1 (8bit,no parity,1 stopbit)
    CLOCAL  : local connection, no modem contol
    CREAD   : enable receiving characters
    */
    newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;

    /*
    IGNPAR  : ignore bytes with parity errors
    ICRNL   : map CR to NL (otherwise a CR input on the other computer
            will not terminate input)
    otherwise make device raw (no other input processing)
    */
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;

    /*
    Raw output.
    */
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;

    /*
    ICANON  : enable canonical input
    disable all echo functionality, and don't send signals to calling program
    */
    newtio.c_lflag = ICANON;

    /* 
    initialize all control characters 
    default values can be found in /usr/include/termios.h, and are given
    in the comments, but we don't need them here
    */
    newtio.c_cc[VINTR]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-c */ 
    newtio.c_cc[VQUIT]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-\ */
    newtio.c_cc[VERASE]   = 0;     /* del */
    newtio.c_cc[VKILL]    = 0;     /* @ */
    newtio.c_cc[VEOF]     = 4;     /* Ctrl-d */
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME]    = 0;     /* inter-character timer unused */
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN]     = 1;     /* blocking read until 1 character arrives */
    newtio.c_cc[VSWTC]    = 0;     /* '\0' */
    newtio.c_cc[VSTART]   = 0;     /* Ctrl-q */ 
    newtio.c_cc[VSTOP]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-s */
    newtio.c_cc[VSUSP]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-z */
    newtio.c_cc[VEOL]     = 0;     /* '\0' */
    newtio.c_cc[VREPRINT] = 0;     /* Ctrl-r */
    newtio.c_cc[VDISCARD] = 0;     /* Ctrl-u */
    newtio.c_cc[VWERASE]  = 0;     /* Ctrl-w */
    newtio.c_cc[VLNEXT]   = 0;     /* Ctrl-v */
    newtio.c_cc[VEOL2]    = 0;     /* '\0' */

    /* 
    now clean the modem line and activate the settings for the port
    */
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);

    /*
    terminal settings done, now handle input
    In this example, inputting a 'z' at the beginning of a line will 
    exit the program.
    */
    while (STOP==FALSE) {     /* loop until we have a terminating condition */
    /* read blocks program execution until a line terminating character is 
    input, even if more than 255 chars are input. If the number
    of characters read is smaller than the number of chars available,
    subsequent reads will return the remaining chars. res will be set
    to the actual number of characters actually read */
    res = read(fd,buf,255); 
    memcpy(sensorDatas, buf, strlen(buf)+1);
    buf[res]=0;             /* set end of string, so we can printf */
    sensorDatas[res]=0;
    printf("%s", sensorDatas);

    /* Segmentation of Datas received from Arduino  */
    if(sscanf(sensorDatas,"%*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d %*[^:]:%d"
                   ,&accLowX,&accLowY,&accLowZ,&accHighX,&accHighY,&accHighZ)==6) {
        // do something 

        printf( "accLowX : %d\n", accLowX);
        printf( "accLowY : %d\n", accLowY);
        printf( "accLowZ : %d\n", accLowZ);

    }


    }
    /* restore the old port settings */
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&oldtio);
}
```